# How do I time how long my pg_restore takes in the command line?

Tags: command-line, time, postgresql

I'm trying to track the amount of time the process takes for when I move around my data and upgrade my web app. From the command line, how would I track the amount of time elapsed from when the pg_restore command starts to when it finishes?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/command-to-monitor-elapsed-time-in-background .

Answer (score 5):

The same way you'd time any other shell command: use the `time` command.

```
$ time pg_restore ...
real    1m0.000s
user    1m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Here, `real` is the elapsed wall clock time, which is probably the only meaningful value, since most of the work is being done in a separate process (the PostgreSQL server).